# Eclipse rename EditorPart

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse plugin project that has an editor view. So I extend the `EditorPart` class. Initially, the `init` Method is called and I can also call the method `setPartName` there to update the label of the tab like:

```
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
    super.init(site, input);
    //...
    setPartName(filename);
}
```

the `setPartName` method is a protected method. I have now another class (let's say `DataModel`) that is the data model for my editor. Is it possible to update the editors part from this class? Because there was a renaming of the file inside `DataModel` class and now I want to show the new filename / replace the old one.

**EDIT**: it's a gef4-based project, the `View` (extending `AbstractFXEditor`, which extends `EditorPart`) creates an instance of `DataModel` in the `init` method:

```
IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput) input).getFile();
URI inputUri = URI.createURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
getContentViewer().getContents().setAll(createContents(inputUri));
```

and the `createContents(URI)` method creates the instance of `DataModel`.

Thanks

Comment: So declare a public method in your editor that calls setPartName and call that method from your DataModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whops, it was a long day. Can answer by myself...

Just add `View` to the `DataModel` constructor, declaring a public method that calls the `setPartName`, call it from wherever you want to from inside `DataModel` and it's done.